# Quick filter and Row level security

Tags: tableau-api

Could you please provide the procedure to implement the user filters based on the below condition.
Engineer should see his data related to him only, he should not see
another engineer's data in report. The S1 Team Techlead should see
the S1 team engineer's data only. Manger should see the data of all
engineers and Techlead data of his team only .Global manager can see all employees data . Employees are around 1500. Then how to implement data security among them.

The below image describes the table structure

[image]

Comment: User filters are documented in Tableau's on line help  http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/help.htm#publish_userfilters.html Is there some specific difficulty?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for quick response. I have already seen that article ,but I din't get the exact solution . Could you please have deep look of my requirement and update me the process to be implemented. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did the documentation not cover your specific use case?

Comment: No secrets here, just brute force. You can separate the users in groups, and use ISMEMBEROF() function to do the filters (for the ones who have access to more people http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/functions_functions_user.html